# How to write summarised Prometheus metric and report ok/nok based on group of other metric

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-operator

We have two individual Prometheus metrics network_status_up_dut and network_status_down_dut which reports actual status of either 1 or 0 from the nodes.

I am looking to create a master or summarised metric based network_overall_status_dut which should return 1 if the both network_status_up_dut & network_status_down_dut reports 1, if any one reports 0 then network_overall_status_dut should report 0.

We will do PromQL Query the netwrok_overall_status_dut metric to report overall status.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to use those two metrics to create panel, you can simply use query

```
(network_status_up_dut == 1 and network_status_down_dut == 1)
 or network_status_up_dut == 0
 or network_status_down_dut
```

It will return `network_status_up_dut` if both metrics are 1 or if it is 0. Else `network_status_down_dut` will be returned.

---

If you need this as a separate metric you can use [recording rules](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/recording_rules/), to create metric based on others.

```
  - name: network_overall_status_dut
    rules:
    - record: network_overall_status_dut
      expr: (network_status_up_dut == 1 and network_status_down_dut == 1) or network_status_up_dut == 0 or network_status_down_dut
```